# What type of encoding/compression is this?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compression

So, I am trying to decode/decompress web socket receive, but I don`t know what should I use, gzip, lib and etc.

```
def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)


def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)


def on_close(ws, close_status_code, close_msg):
    print("### closed ###")


def on_open(ws):
    print("[*] Opened connection.")  
    msg = ["lang", "AA==", "data", "WINLINE", "getdate"]
    [ws.send(m) for m in msg]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(
        url="wss://wss.winline.ru/data_ng?",
        on_open=on_open,
        on_message=on_message,
        # header=headers
    )

    ws.run_forever(dispatcher=rel)  # Set dispatcher to automatic reconnection
    rel.signal(2, rel.abort)  # Keyboard Interrupt
    rel.dispatch()
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
```

This is websocket receive:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x035\xce\xb1\r\xc20\x14E\xd1\xfb\xfc\xbfm\x08\x10E\x08\t\xa5a\x02W)Y!\x12\x1d\x13\xc0\x12L\xc0<\xd9"\xb3\x90\x96\x01\x88\x0b\xf4\x8a\xdb\x9c\xe2\xbd@o\xc4\x83xn\xf5U(\xb2"\x9f\x89O\xd2@.\xda\x0cl/4\'v\r{8@\x0b&\x1c\x085Y\x9fu\xa1\xf7\xde\xad\xa3\xc3\'\x9b,^\xb9y\x82\xa3g\xb8\xbb\xf8\xb3E\x8b\xacZ\xaf6V\x9b\xb4\x1e\xc8\xa3\x8f\xfe\x03Iq)b\x8e\x00\x00\x00'
```

If i will use `gzip.decompress(message)` it will looks:

```
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xd3a\xc8a``\xe0a\xb04\xd536\xd4325\x01b\x00\x99\xe6\x82\x81\x14\x00\x00\x00'
,l
  95.31.254.25
b'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x0bc\x00\x00-\xe88\xad\x02\x00\x00\x00'
V
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: A magic number of 0x1F8B (the first 2 bytes of your bytestring) indicates GZIP compression.

Comment: @MattDMo  oh, cool, but I am tried to use gzip and its still decoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your "This is websocket receive:" is a perfectly valid gzip stream. When I use Python's `gzip.decompress()` on it,  it decompresses correctly to:

```
b'y\x00\x00\x01\x87\x00\x01\x00c\x00\x05\x17\x0e\x01\xf4\x01\x02,\x01\x03,\x01\x04\xc8\x00\x05d\x00\x062\x00\x07,\x01\x082\x00\t\x1e\x00\n\x14\x00\x0b\n\x00\x0c\x00\x00\r\x00\x00\x0e\x00\x00\x03\x01\x00\x04\x00\x00\x00\x02\x01\x00\x04\x00\x07\x01\xea\x01\xea\x01\x02\x19\x04\x19\x04\x03\x10\x00\x10\x00\x04\xb1\x03\xb1\x03\x05:\x00N\x04\x06\x00\x00\x12\x04\x07\x00\x00U\x04\x01\x00\x00\x07\x01\xea\x01\xea\x01\x02\xeb\x01\xeb\x01\x03\x19\x04\x19\x04\x04\x10\x00\x10\x00\x05\xb1\x03\xb1\x03\x06\x01\x00\x01\x00\x07K\x04K\x04'
```

Comment: great! Mark, thx for u help! So but its still decoded, am I right? So, should I use:  

```data = gzip.decompress(message)
    print(data.decode())```

How can I convert it to utf-8 string?

Comment: I think you mean "it's still _encoded_". It has been decompressed. You know the source of information, so it is up to you to figure out what it means. It is not UTF-8 data.

Comment: Ok, It has been decompressed and now I should decode it? I think, now Im should find a right way to do this and get UTF-8 string. Yeah, u are right. I know, that final data should be a UTF-8 string.

Comment: You should _interpret_ it. It is binary data that has some meaning. It is not in any way a string of readable text.

Comment: No, no. Its string data Mark, 100%, I did same with Ruby and got this: 

```500m Women'ddL500m'ddN1000m'ddfSnowboardcross'dd�Parallel Giant Slalom'dd�Simulated Reality League'dMalaysia'dd'Fiji'ddGermany'dd� Formula 1'dd�
       Netherlands'ddSimulated Reality Women'ddCameroon'dd�Russia'ddVirtual Bundesliga'ddtSolomonIslands'dd�MotoGP'dd�Belgium'dd�Kenya'dd�United Arab Emirates'dd�Nepal'```

Comment: Ruby code was:   

```ws.on :message do |event|
    p event.data
    gz = Zlib::GzipReader.new(StringIO.new(event.data.pack('c*')))    
    puts gz.read
end```

Comment: No, that is not the data in your example.